# Looping through columns to compare and transform values in M

Tags: powerquery, m

I am merging two tables with identical columns. For each column in table A, I want to replace the value with null if the value is the same as in table B. The reason is for upserting into a database. If i can replace all of the unchanged values with null, i can streamline the integration flow.

I'd like to do this in power query instead of using VBA and SQL with ADODB datasets. My M is decent but more for UI based queries.

the way I am thinking of it is after I merge the two tables and expand the 2nd table with a prefix (say "A")

```
For each row in the table
 For x = 1 to y (the number of columns in each table)
  If column(x).value = column(Ax).value then
   set x.value = null
 Next x
```

I haven't been able to find anything specifically related to this and I apologize in advance if I missed an easy to find resource.  Thanks.

Merging old data with new (on ID internal join) in power query and expanding the new data

| ID | volume | mass | transparency | volume1 | mass1 | transparency1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15.14 | 238.2279 | 0.15 | 15.14 | 238.4679 | 0.15 |
| 2 | 14.76 | 232.2486 | 0.26 | 13.23 | 208.1741 | 0.22 |
| 3 | 13.79 | 216.98565 | 0.11 | 13.79 | 216.9857 | 0.11 |
| 4 | 19.01 | 299.12235 | 0.09 | 19.01 |  | 299.1224 |
| 5 | 10.97 | 172.61295 | 0.49 | 11.03 | 173.5571 | 0.49 |

output I want

| ID | volume | mass | transparency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 238.4679 | null |
| 2 | 13.23 | 208.17405 | 0.22 |
| 3 | null | null | null |
| 4 | null | null | 0.08 |
| 5 | 11.03 | 173.55705 | null |

Comment: Please **edit your question** to provide a representative data sample as **text** that can be copy/pasted.  Will the entries in Table B be in the same column/row as Table A?  Or might they be in the same column but a different row?  Any chance of duplicate entries in either table?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Holidays and all that...

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```vb
let
    Table1 =
        #table(
            type table [
                #"ID" = Int64.Type,
                #"a.volume" = Number.Type,
                #"a.mass" = Number.Type,
                #"a.transparency" = Number.Type
            ],
            {
                { 1, 15.14, 238.2279, 0.15},
                { 2, 14.76, 232.2486, 0.26},
                { 3, 13.79, 216.9857, 0.11},
                { 4, 19.01, 299.1224, 0.09},
                { 5, 10.97, 172.6129, 0.49}
            }
        ),
    Table2 =
        #table(
            type table [
                #"ID" = Int64.Type,
                #"b.volume" = Number.Type,
                #"b.mass" = Number.Type,
                #"b.transparency" = Number.Type
            ],
            {
                { 1, 15.14, 238.4679, 0.15},
                { 2, 13.23, 208.1741, 0.22},
                { 3, 13.79, 216.9857, 0.11},
                { 4, 19.01, 299.1224, 0.08},
                { 5, 11.03, 173.5571, 0.49}
            }
        ),
    Merge = Table.NestedJoin(Table1, {"ID"}, Table2, {"ID"}, "Table2", JoinKind.Inner),
    Expand = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Merge, "Table2", {"b.volume", "b.mass", "b.transparency"}, {"b.volume", "b.mass", "b.transparency"}),
    add_Volume = Table.AddColumn(Expand, "volume", each if [a.volume]=[b.volume] then null else [b.volume], type number),
    add_Mass = Table.AddColumn(add_Volume, "mass", each if [a.mass]=[b.mass] then null else [b.mass], type number),
    add_Transparency = Table.AddColumn(add_Mass, "transparency", each if [a.transparency]=[b.transparency] then null else [b.transparency], type number),
    delete_Columns = Table.RemoveColumns(add_Transparency,{"a.volume", "a.mass", "a.transparency", "b.volume", "b.mass", "b.transparency"})
in
    delete_Columns
```

The steps:

1. Create `Table1`:

   | ID | a.volume | a.mass | a.transparency |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 15.14 | 238.2279 | 0.15 |
   | 2 | 14.76 | 232.2486 | 0.26 |
   | 3 | 13.79 | 216.9857 | 0.11 |
   | 4 | 19.01 | 299.1224 | 0.09 |
   | 5 | 10.97 | 172.6129 | 0.49 |
2. Create `Table2`:

   | ID | b.volume | b.mass | b.transparency |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 15.14 | 238.4679 | 0.15 |
   | 2 | 13.23 | 208.1741 | 0.22 |
   | 3 | 13.79 | 216.9857 | 0.11 |
   | 4 | 19.01 | 299.1224 | 0.08 |
   | 5 | 11.03 | 173.5571 | 0.49 |
3. Merge them together using the `[ID]` column, then expand the join.
4. Add three custom columns to check if the value in table `b` is the same as the value in table `a`. If same, return `null`, if different, use value from table `b`.
5. Delete all the columns from the original two tables.

The result:

| ID | volume | mass | transparency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | 238.4679 | *null* |
| 2 | 13.23 | 208.1741 | 0.22 |
| 3 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 4 | *null* | *null* | 0.08 |
| 5 | 11.03 | 173.5571 | *null* |